# Category pages: removing product sorting menu

Tags: category, category-products, magento2.4.5p1

Can anyone advise on removing the product sorting menu on category and sub category pages? I've manually positioned products and limited sorting to 'position only,' but the menu still shows on the front end. I'd prefer not to hide it with CSS since I want it to not load at all. Removing it from category templates resets sorting to default; ignoring my position request. Any suggestions for a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but you can follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190747/how-to-remove-the-sorting-and-positioning-tools-from-the-category-page-in-fronte)