# How customize cart view page in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, shopping-cart

I tried to create a `layout` and `phtml` template and a block for add something to cart view page.

I added something, but When I want to choose `referenceBlock` the content disappear.

Actually I'm going to add some column like price and number to cart table view, but I think it could not find the block! I appreciate any help of you

Here is my code:

> MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/Block/Productpoint.php`

```
<?php

namespace MagenCheckout\CheckoutField\Block;

class Productpoint extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = [])
    {
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

> MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="MagenCheckout_CheckoutField" setup_version="0.0.8">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

> MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
        <block class="MagenCheckout\CheckoutField\Block\Productpoint" name="cart_item_addional_info" template="MagenCheckout_CheckoutField::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

> MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml

```
<p>
   <?php echo 'Your Discount'; ?>
</p>
```

> MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'MagenCheckout_CheckoutField',
__DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

1. Update `MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/etc/module.xml` to

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="MagenCheckout_CheckoutField" setup_version="0.0.8">
          <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
           <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
          </sequence>
       </module>
   </config>
   ```
2. Update `MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
          <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MagenCheckout_CheckoutField::cart/form.phtml</argument>
           </action>
           <block class="MagenCheckout\CheckoutField\Block\Productpoint" name="cart_item_addional_info" template="MagenCheckout_CheckoutField::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml"/>
          </referenceBlock>
      </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Copy `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml` to `MagenCheckout/CheckoutField/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml`, and place this code to the end of file

   ```
   <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('cart_item_addional_info'); ?>
   ```

Comment: You mean I should edit form.phtml file in magento core?

Comment: @MTaheri of course not :) you should override it in your own module or in your theme.

Comment: Actually I'm new to magento. :-| Could you please explain more about how should I override form.phtml in my module?

Comment: @MTaheri I've updated the answer, could you try it and tell me the result :)

Comment: quan-le Thank you for your reply, my cart table disappeared now! I don't know the problem

Comment: Problem was the address of this: MagenCheckout_CheckoutField::checkout/cart/form.phtml

Comment: quan-le Now I'm going to add a <td> tag which contains some info of product, but product row of form shows by <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?> and how should I access to <td> tags seperately?

Comment: You could add it by override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`. Please refer to topics about override template file like [this topic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/) to do it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks but how could I override child of block with name `checkout.cart.item.renderers` which has no name and use default.phtml as template in `module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/` path