# Magento 2 How is Layout.xml rendered to html file

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I have this *catalog_product_view.xml* in my theme **layout** folder.

I want to edit the *html code* for this part `all-products-left-wrapper`,

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="all-products-left-wrapper" label="All Products Left Wrapper" as="all-products-left-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="all-products-left-wrapper" before="-">    
    </container>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/mediaimage.phtml" />  
</referenceContainer>
```

But I have searched all over my Magento folders, I simply can't find the **phtml** file for this?

But on the front-end, when I look at the source code from browser, I do see this is generated `<div class="all-products-left-wrapper">`. So how does Magento 2 render it's **.xml** files to html?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of a few SE answers [(this for example)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2), but the short answer is that default theme files are under `vendor/magento` and you can copy them to your theme just like in Magento 1, but there is a significant difference in naming conventions for the pathname in Magento 2.

In your example, the default file should be located at
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/mediaimage.phtml`

If you have an [activated and applied theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/112655/33071) (we will use Your_Theme for this example).  The file can be copied to

`app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/mediaimage.phtml`

and then you can edit away!

Comment: The other awswer are about how to override .phtml file. this is not the issue for me, as I already known how to override the .phtml file. my issue in my question was actually, I can't even find the .phtml file for the  <container name="all-products-left-wrapper"> from the .xml file. if i can find the .phtml file for this container, then I can override it.

Comment: @xxx It is a strangely-named file that I haven't ran across while working on media templates.  Have you found anything by turning on template hints?