# Limit customer firstname and lastname in m2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, magento2-enterprise, name

How can we limit the character of first name and last name of customer. For example I want only 30 characters are valid to enter in first & last name. As of now there is no limit on character we can add as many character we want.

Looking for advices 
Thanks

Comment: do you want to limit 30 character individually for first name and last name OR in combined name (first name + last name) ?

Comment: yes individually

Comment: for individual ,  you can use maxlength property of text field of first name and last name like this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Comment: no but how can we do this in magento 2.  I am aware of maxlength="10" feature

Comment: you need to override template file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml` and need to put maxlength property there.

Comment: you can check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2)  how to override template file

Comment: @Daniel_12 but for show first name and last name there is input field required,maxlenght is the attribute of input tag.so i think it works

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code**

```
<input type="text" name="first name" id="first_name"
       class="admin__control-text required-entry validate-alphanum-with-spaces validate-length maximum-length-30"
       maxlength="30" />
```

**whatever you want set input field length,set in maxlength attribute**

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't stop the spam accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override core template file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml` in your theme folder using this link -

> [How to override .phtml files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2)

and need to put **maxlength** property in `input` text field of first name and last name as suggested here.

> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        <item name="max-words" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        <item name="max-words" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Working on Magento 2.4.3 Tested and verified.Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

1. You should override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml` in your theme. Then you can add classes "validate-length maximum-length-30" to those inputs.
2. You should also override it in checkout. You need to find information how to modify validation of checkout fields before render them. You can do it e.g by plugin.