# How to change Text of qty TO quantity in minicart

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Hello I want to override magento 2 Mini cart  UIComponent's Text from qty to Quantity  please tell How to do so 
Thanks,

Comment: magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml >> you can override this phtml in your theme and change lable of QTY to quantity.

Comment: overriding meaning creating layout / *.xml ? correct

Comment: Actually you can copy this file from /vendor.... to your theme directory with same directory structure so file will be executed from your theme.

Comment: fro overriding phtml this post will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2

Comment: ok i will try if any needed i will coment thanks for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume, you are using a custom theme Vendor_YourTheme

Please copy

> **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

Paste into your custom theme.

> **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

Now replace label  "**Qty**"  with "**Quantity**" as follows:

```
<label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Quantity', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}">
</label>
```

Please empty your pub/static/frontend/ folder by running below command and flush Magento cache.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Note: To display mini-cart "quantity" label properly, you may need to adjust some css class.**

[image]

Comment: if i want do do it in code folder? not in design

Comment: @AdarshShukla  It is more simple and  straightforward to do this customisation in template instead code folder .if you want to do it in a code folder then you may need to overwrite KO template html file for the JS component "item.renderer". You can see the xml file ( YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml ) where "default.html" template assigned to mini-cart "item.renderer" component.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Translate Inline

Select `Enable for Storefront` to `Yes`.

No go to frontend and you will see selectable items for every block that can be translated. Select Cart icon, click on the book icon. Then change the text, and save.

> Note - In case translate items are not reflected you can fush cachen and run deployment command
>   and retry

**Another** way of doing can be(I have not tried)
Simple override Checkout module like `Magento_Checkout` in your custom theme folder, and copy/paste folder `i18n`, and there write text like -

```
"Qty","Quantity"
```