# How to override a advance search & orders return page in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, advanced-search

In magento 2  how to override a advance search page and order return 
page in my custom theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Override advance search 
Copy

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml

to your

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Theme_name/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/form.phtml

For Order return page 
Copy

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/guest/form.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Theme_name/Magento_Sales/templates/guest/form.phtml

For more details on how to override phtml files in Magento 2 you may refer this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116463/38990)

Answer (score 2):

To **Advance Search** below file Copy and override in your custom theme:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/form.phtml

To **Order Return** Below file Copy and Overrirde

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/guest/form.phtml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Sales/templates/guest/form.phtml