# Exact Path for New phtml File

Tags: theme, frontend, overrides, html, directory

I am trying to override a core phtml file following the advice in this question [How to override .phtml files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/how-to-override-phtml-files-in-magento-2).  I am not able to get it to work and I am wondering in general how the path of the override file is determined so I can know if I am putting it in the correct location.  For example, I am overriding the file

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

and I am not quite sure if the right path would be

app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

or

app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/default.phtml.

My intuition goes with the second choice since the directories templates and product are already present while the view and everything after in the first choice are not.  I have not been able to get either to work and I am wondering which one is correct or if it is supposed to be a third location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the typo in the module name (Magento_Catalog), this second solution should be: `app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magneto_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  What I did was copy the original to this location, add a php echo test statement, run bin/magento setup:upgrade, and then cleared the cache and refreshed the page.  Do you have any ideas about what would cause changes not to appear?

Comment: Sorry, it should be like: `app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magneto_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.